# Kafka java client based on SASL_SSL, ignoring configs for truststore and taking default certs

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

The consumer I am trying using default certs for handshake, ignoring the certs defined in Config, what is went wrong?

When trying to consume messages, it is using default certs and  raising SSL Handshake error.

```
    public class Consumer {

    final KafkaConsumer<String,String> mConsumer;
    final Logger mLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);

    private Properties consumerProperties(String bootstrapServer,String username, String password,String certPasswd) {
        //String serializer = StringSerializer.class.getName();
        String serializer = StringSerializer.class.getName();
        String deserializer = StringDeserializer.class.getName();
        String jaasTemplate = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"%s\" password=\"%s\";";
        String jaasCfg = String.format(jaasTemplate, username, password);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,bootstrapServer);
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, serializer);
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,serializer);
        props.setProperty("security.inter.broker.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
        props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServer);
        props.setProperty("group.id", username + "-nprod-consumer");
        //props.setProperty("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.setProperty("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        props.setProperty("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.setProperty("key.deserializer", deserializer);
        props.setProperty("value.deserializer", deserializer);
        props.setProperty("key.serializer", serializer);
        props.setProperty("value.serializer", serializer);
        props.setProperty("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
        props.setProperty("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");
        props.setProperty("ssl.keystore.location","client.keystore.jks");
        props.setProperty("ssl.keystore.password",certPasswd);
        props.setProperty("ssl.key.password",certPasswd);
        props.setProperty("ssl.enabled.protocols","TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1");
        props.setProperty("ssl.client.auth","required");
        props.setProperty("ssl.truststore.location","client.truststore.jks");
        props.setProperty("ssl.truststore.password",certPasswd);
        props.setProperty("sasl.jaas.config", jaasCfg);
        return props;
    }

    Consumer(String bootstrapServer,String username, String password,String certPassword) {
        Properties props = consumerProperties(bootstrapServer,username,password,certPassword);
        mConsumer= new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        mLogger.info("Consumer Initialized");
    }

    void read(String topic) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        mConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = mConsumer.poll(1000);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                System.out.printf("%s [%d] offset=%d, key=%s, value=\"%s\"\n",
                                  record.topic(), record.partition(),
                                  record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
            }
        }
    }
    void close(){
        mLogger.info("Closing Consumer");
        mConsumer.close();
    }
}
```

Please advice, how I can ignore default certs and enforce the certs defined in configs for consumer.

Comment: Why are you defining inter broker protocol or serializers on a consumer client? And you're using SSL, so why is the SASL mechanism as PLAIN? And what do you mean by "default certs"? How did you create them?

Comment: I received kafka server details as follows "Kafka connection string (Kafka security protocol is SASL SSL, SASL mechanism is plain)", default certs means, the certs already available in client machine java trust store.

Comment: @cricket_007 that says it is using certs from cacerts,but I want to connect with customer trust store.

Comment: @user3364699 how do you know it is looking at the default certs? I think O have the same problem and would like to know how you solved it